# What are the best ways of improving SEO when money is not an option

Tags: seo

I have written [www.studentnews.co.za](http://www.studentnews.co.za) and for some reason it takes weeks for search results to appear on google. I took a chance and wrote my own cms applying some best seo practice i have read from around the web. If i chose wordpress for the site would i have been in the same position?

Im so lost with seo can anyone help thanks

Comment: "applying some best seo practice"... what best seo practices did you apply after all?

Comment: adding alt tags. renaming images. proper use of h1 tags. optimizing     meta tags,descriptions and length. page titles ,url rewriting. basically thats its.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer should deal with your questions:

[How do search engines find relevant content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967076/how-do-search-engines-find-relevant-content/4036627#4036627)

The only thing you can do when everything is perfectly optimal is getting backlinks, interacting with other sites, get a community, maintain your content.

Answer (score 0):

Its widely speculated that there is something called [sandbox effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_effect).
So please wait before any drastic measures.

---

And meanwhile, browse the higher ranked websites on your search critieria for more room for improvement on your own SEO rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're website is new? there are probably thousand of website launched every day and crawler trying hard to get the most of them.

if this happened then you need to leverage your website to get indexed.

after you're done with you in-page SEO then you need to get inbound link (link from other website to your website). please do search around for there are many good article about inbound link.